# Value selection between two Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two different arrays - **Name** and **Email** in javascript. Values in the two arrays correspond to each other; *Name[0] has email value at Email[0]*. Values from array Name are used for a dropdown in the HTML page. Now when the user selects a name (dropdown) and clicks on **Send** button, email should be send to the person whose name is selected in the dropdown. How to lookup in the second array based on the value selected by User in the dropdown?
Name and Email arrays will always have dynamic values

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you use object for the 2nd array? var emails = {}; emails["userName1"] = email1; emails["username2"] = email2; then when the drop down changes sendEmail(emails[dropDownValue]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var email = Email[document.getElementById("names").selectedIndex]
```

Answer (score 0):

Value of selected index is to provide the required value, so you can initialize it:

```js
function getValue(){      
    var emailSelectedUser = document.getElementById("names").value;
    alert(emailSelectedUser)
 }
```

```html
 <select id='names'>
  <option value="email@address.com">User Name</option>
   <option value="email2@address.com">User 2</option>
 </select> 
<input type='button' value='submit' onclick='getValue()' />
```